# How do i make a light dark specific css tag?

Tags: html, css, class

### **Light Dark** Css

```css
body.light + .mat-medium {
  background: rgba(246,246,246,0.60);
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(1);
}
```

```html
<body class="light">
    <div class="mat-medium"></div>
</body>
```

I was hoping that the div would display the `mat-medium` class because the body had the class `light` but it displayed a blank div.

> View [the repl](https://replit.com/join/ggxogqjxus-gabrieltoy1).

Comment: There's no such thing as a CSS tag. Did you mean a rule? Also, you've implemented a sibling selector. The body and the div are not siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to fix your selector to select the div inside the body.
   You used **element + element** selector, which selects the first 'div' element that is placed immediately after 'body' element, but you need **element > element** selector to select the child 'div'
2. Also you need to set some width/height to the div to make it visible or add some content inside it.

```css
body.light>.mat-medium {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(216, 246, 246, 0.60);
  backdrop-filter: blur(30px) saturate(1);
}
```

```html
<body class="light">
  <div class="mat-medium"></div>
</body>
```